# pytest and argparse: test failed because of command-line arguments

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, argparse

I have `client.py` module that uses `argparse` for CLI:

```
class Client:
    #some logic
    ...

def main(arguments=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("n", nargs='?', type=int, default=10, help="number of threads")
    parser.add_argument("f", nargs='?', default="urls.txt", help="file with URLs")
    args = parser.parse_args(arguments)

    #some logic unrelated to argparse
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And there is `tests.py` module with test:

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import patch
import client

    def test(self):
        with patch.object(sys, 'argv', ['n', 10, 'f', "urls.txt"]):
            client.main()
```

`client.py` module works fine - in CLI and in scripts. But when it calls in pytest tests - an error appears:

```
    def test(self):
        with patch.object(sys, 'argv', ['n', 10, 'f', "urls.txt"]):    
>           client.main()

test_client_server.py:60: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
client.py:55: in main
    args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py:1862: in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py:1895: in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py:1938: in _parse_known_args
    option_tuple = self._parse_optional(arg_string)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = ArgumentParser(prog='n', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
arg_string = 10

    def _parse_optional(self, arg_string):
        # if it's an empty string, it was meant to be a positional
        if not arg_string:
            return None
    
        # if it doesn't start with a prefix, it was meant to be positional
>       if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
E       TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\argparse.py:2228: TypeError
```

I have tried to mock `sys.argv` - and it mocks fine with `['n', 10, 'f', 'urls.txt']` but test failed with error anyway.
Why `arg_string = 10` in error? Don't understand it.

Comment: Should the arguments be defined as '-n' and '-f' - flagged arguments rather than positionals?

Comment: @hpaulj It has no effect on the error, all the same

Comment: All the `argv` values must be strings,  `['n','10'.'f'.'text']`, not an int like `10`

Comment: Your `argv` is supposed to mock the `sys.argv[1:]` which will always be a list of strings (possibly empty).  Putting an `int` in this list raises an unusual error.  At this point in parsing, it's trying to classify this value, expecting either a '-n' or 'n' string, not a number.  I understand the parser code well enough to deduce what's happening - after some thought.  This is not the kind of error that `pytest` should be handling.

Answer (score 0):

Your parser, without all the pytest baggage (in a `ipython` session):

```
In [10]: def main(arguments=None):
    ...:     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    ...:     parser.add_argument("n", nargs='?', type=int, default=10, help="number of threads")
    ...:     parser.add_argument("f", nargs='?', default="urls.txt", help="file with URLs")
    ...:     args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
    ...:     return args
```

The help:

```
In [11]: main(['-h'])
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [n] [f]

positional arguments:
  n           number of threads (default: 10)
  f           file with URLs (default: urls.txt)

options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

A valid argv list - two strings, for the two positional arguments:

```
In [12]: main(['10','text.file'])
Out[12]: Namespace(n=10, f='text.file')
```

Trying your `argv`, but with a '10' string:

```
In [13]: main(['n', '10', 'f', "urls.txt"])
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [n] [f]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: argument n: invalid int value: 'n'
```

It's trying to parse the 'n' string as an `int`.  You defined positionals, not flagged arguments, so the 'n' and 'f' strings don't belong.

Your error - with the number `10` instead of the string:

```
In [14]: main(['n', 10, 'f', "urls.txt"])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

With positionals like this, you have to provide the 'n' argument first; you can't skip it.  That's how the two '?' nargs are handled.

Changing the parser to use `optionals` (flagged) arguments:

```
In [15]: def main(arguments=None):
    ...:     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    ...:     parser.add_argument("-n", nargs='?', type=int, default=10, help="number of threads")
    ...:     parser.add_argument("-f", nargs='?', default="urls.txt", help="file with URLs")
    ...:     args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
    ...:     return args
    ...:
```

Now it's ok to include the '-n' flag string in argv.  And we can include any combination of these:

```
In [16]: main(['-n', '10','-f', "urls.txt"])
Out[16]: Namespace(n=10, f='urls.txt')

In [17]: main(['-f', "urls.txt"])
Out[17]: Namespace(n=10, f='urls.txt')

In [18]: main(['-n', '10'])
Out[18]: Namespace(n=10, f='urls.txt')

In [19]: main([])
Out[19]: Namespace(n=10, f='urls.txt')
```

If we add a `const` parameter, each of these arguments can now be a 3 way 'switch', default, const or user value:

```
In [20]: def main(arguments=None):
    ...:     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    ...:     parser.add_argument("-n", nargs='?', type=int, default=10, help="number of threads", const=100)
    ...:     parser.add_argument("-f", nargs='?', default="urls.txt", help="file with URLs", const='foobar')
    ...:     args = parser.parse_args(arguments)
    ...:     return args
    ...:     

In [21]: main(['-n', '10'])
Out[21]: Namespace(n=10, f='urls.txt')

In [22]: main(['-n', '10','-f'])
Out[22]: Namespace(n=10, f='foobar')

In [23]: main(['-n','-f'])
Out[23]: Namespace(n=100, f='foobar')
```

If the `pytest` has problems like with `argparse`, make sure the parser itself is working as you want and expect.  Or to put it differently, make sure your `pytest` values make sense for the parser - unless you are delibrately testing for some bad inputs.